# Upgrade RHEL OS

Tags: rhel, upgrade

I have a piece of software installed on a RHEL 6.7 machine.

To update this piece of software to the latest version I have to update the operating system in two steps:

1. First I have to update the RHEL from verse 6.7 to vers. 6.8.
2. Then I have to update the RHEL from the vers. 6.8 to vers. 6.9.

Can you tell me the steps / commands to be performed?

Answer (score 6):

There’s no need for separate steps to upgrade to each point release; you can upgrade to the latest current release (6.10) directly.

```
yum check-update
```

[will list the available updates](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/ch-yum#sec-Checking_For_Updates), and

```
yum upgrade
```

will upgrade all the installed packages. You should reboot once the upgrade is complete.

If you do want to upgrade to each point release, one at a time, there are a number of ways to do so:

- using `subscription-manager`, you can pin systems to a given point-release:

  ```
  subscription-manager release --set=6.8
  yum clean all
  yum upgrade
  ```

  will upgrade to 6.8 only;
- using the installation media, you can upgrade an existing system to the installation media’s point release; *e.g.* for 6.8, download [the 6.8 binary DVD](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/69/ver=/rhel---6/6.8/x86_64/product-software), boot it and select the upgrade option at boot.

It is also possible to use a binary DVD as a Yum repository, but that shouldn’t be necessary if you have a valid subscription. Pinning the release is a much better approach anyway since that will ensure you still get security patches as appropriate for your system (as long as you run `yum update` regularly).

(This doesn’t take into account any EUS subscriptions you might have. That’s not an issue for 6.8 yet, but it could have an impact for earlier releases.)

Comment: I know this. But I am obliged to do the steps. I have to update first to the vers. 6.8 and then to 6.9.

Comment: Why do you have to upgrade in steps?

Comment: Because the software / tool that I need to update requires it. Do you know how to do it or not? -_-

Comment: @peKa It looks like explicit steps to upgrade specifically to 6.8 is in the posting and the next upgrade to 6.9 can be easily followed. Are you having any issues in following these instructions? FYI, I have never heard of any application software dictating how an OS should be upgraded. What is the package that is putting this requirement on you?

Comment: @Doug to be fair I added the step-by-step part recently, after peKa’s last comment.

Comment: It is a proprietary software of HP. Do not talk about it ... xD -_-. Thank you for the answer